# Convert a Date to a Julian javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I would like to convert a date such as `2014/09/30` to a Julian date. Converting a date should return an integer.

The reason why I want this integer is to use it in a subtract formula, and then revert the final results back to a date.

How can I convert a date to a Julian and then convert the final results to a date?

Comment: Thanks, i was able to use the following code: Date.prototype.getJulian = function() {
      return Math.ceil((this / 86400000) - (this.getTimezoneOffset()/1440) + 2440587.5);
}

var valDate = input1[0];
var dt = new Date(valDate);
var julian_dt = dt.getJulian();

output1 = julian_dt;

Comment: Is there an example on how to do the reverse ... convert a julian to a regular date in this format "2014/09/30" ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Date.prototype.getJulian = function() {
  return Math.ceil((this / 86400000) - (this.getTimezoneOffset()/1440) + 2440587.5);
}

var valDate = input1[0];
var dt = new Date(valDate);
var julian_dt = dt.getJulian();

output1 = julian_dt;
```

i was able to use the code above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should get familiar with javascript's `Date` objects. You can subtract one date object from another to find differences in time, and all kinds of other nifty things. It's definitely much cleaner, and less error-prone, than working with strings and integers.